# Press two arrow key at same time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, input, arrow-keys

I have problem with getting two arrow key at same time, for example Up+Right for my player to move to the corner of screen, but I can have only one input at time.
So I have to check every possibility. Is there any way around?
here is my code.

```
void Movement()
{   

    // Input user, arrow keys for move left,right,up and down/////////////////////////////
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x >= -moveRangeX)         //
        physicPlayer.velocity = Vector2.left * moveSpeed;                               //
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x <= moveRangeX)    //
        physicPlayer.velocity = Vector2.right * moveSpeed;                              //
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y <= moveRangeY)       //
        physicPlayer.velocity = Vector2.up * moveSpeed;                                 //
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y >= -moveRangeY)    //
        physicPlayer.velocity = Vector2.down * moveSpeed;                               //
    else                                                                                //
        physicPlayer.velocity = Vector2.zero;                                           //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    // For multiplay input user for example when user press Up+Right arrow keys.//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.x <= moveRangeX && transform.position.y <= moveRangeY)          //
        physicPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(1, 1) * moveSpeed;                                                                                                  //
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.x <= moveRangeX && transform.position.y >= -moveRangeY)  //
        physicPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(1, -1) * moveSpeed;                                                                                                 //
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.x >= -moveRangeX && transform.position.y >= -moveRangeY)  //
        physicPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(-1, -1) * moveSpeed;                                                                                                //
    else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.x >= -moveRangeX && transform.position.y <= moveRangeY)     //
        physicPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(-1, 1) * moveSpeed;                                                                                                 //
    //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

Comment: Remove the `else if`. Replace them with `if`.

Comment: This could be a limitation of your Keyboard (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)). But what Programmer says sounds a lot more likely. You really should not else-if different Key Inputs.

Comment: This is because after the first `if` is true, the rest of the `else if` under it are **ignored**. This is a basic C# stuff and I do encourage you to [learn](https://www.dotnetperls.com/if) the difference before moving on with Unity. I

Comment: I used all the statement `if` `else` `else if` but didn't get what I want. so I code every possibility combination input for arrow keys. As you can see I'm using `Velocity` and `GetKey` method and what I do need is much cleaner and effective method that can used for any similar game. sorry for English.

Comment: Also, so using GetKey and use GetButton, that way your keybinds can be modified by the player.

Answer (score 1):

In your case you should remove the `else if` statement and put it on `if` statement only so your code must follow something like this :

```
Vector3 totalMovement = Vector3.zero;

if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    totalMovement += transform.forward;
}
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    totalMovement -= transform.right;
}
// To ensure same speed on the diagonal, we ensure its magnitude here instead of earlier
player.MovePosition(transform.position + totalMovement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
```

So in your code :

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)){
   physicsPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(1,1) * moveSpeed;
}

if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)){
    physicsPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(-1,1) * moveSpeed;
}
```

Something like that above.

Ps: It's untested but the logic is there . Hope it helps you :)

Comment: I'm not sure whether the lower solution would work out, since the `velocity` is being overriden again when going into the second. Your upper solution seems more convenient, since you can make changes quicker and it's much more easy to read.

Comment: my answer was really untested so i don't know if will work really but what i am pointing there is that you can do the diagonal movement without/removing the `else if` statement .

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final edit for this code. I must use `physicPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, physicPlayer.velocity.y);` insted of this code `physicPlayer.velocity = Vector2.left * moveSpeed;`

It still got some problems but it works.

Thank you.

```
    void Update()
{   
    Movement();
}

void Movement()
{

    physicPlayer.velocity = Vector2.zero;

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) && transform.position.x >= -moveRangeX)
        physicPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(-moveSpeed, physicPlayer.velocity.y);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) && transform.position.x <= moveRangeX)
        physicPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(moveSpeed, physicPlayer.velocity.y);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && transform.position.y <= moveRangeY)
        physicPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(physicPlayer.velocity.x, moveSpeed);

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) && transform.position.y >= -moveRangeY)
        physicPlayer.velocity = new Vector2(physicPlayer.velocity.x, -moveSpeed);

}
```